# Execute Multiple Loop

Tags: wordpress

I go through first loop to get the first list where the category_name="Products".

And the_content I get like this:

Example:

A

B

C

D

I had set a variable name called $product_name = get_the_content() /*$product_category="A" */

Now I wanna execute a inner loop to get the nested list where the category_name="$product_category".

Here is my current code:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=Products'); ?>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                  <a>
                    <div style="padding:5px;background-color:black;margin-bottom:2px;">
                    <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;vertical-align:middle;">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:inline-block;height:100%;">
                        <a><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>

                    <?php $product_category = get_the_content(); ?>
                    <ul>
                    <?php query_posts('category_name=$product_category'); ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                    <li>
                        <a><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

My output just show the first item:

Example:

A

How can I use the multi loop to get the result like:

Example:

A

- product1
- product2

B

- product3

C

- product4

D

- product5
- product6

Comment: `$product_category = get_the_content(); ` will be content be the category name ? that doesnt sound right

Comment: @PushpakPatel I still new in here. This variable assign method I refer on the Wordpress forum site. May I know how to assign "the_content" to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking at is the standard query. You should be using custom posts or custom taxonomy / custom meta to distinguish your different categories from each other. Unless you use php to sort by name.

The class WP_Query allows you to search the database and you can pass parameters to the class before sending

e.g.

```
$args=array(
       'post_type'=> array('product1','product2'),
       'tax_query' => array(
        'relation'=>'AND',
        array(
             'taxonomy'=> 'producttypes',
             'field'=> 'name',
             'terms'=> array('onsale', fullprice)
        )

        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'brands',
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' => array( 'cocacola', 'pepsi', 'gatorade' ),
    )
);

$query= new wp_query($args);
```

there is loads you can do with the query variable afterwards including the loop. For multi loops just create a new instance of the class e.g. $query2= new wp_query($newargs);

reference for all this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query